# How do I use wildmenu effectively?

Tags: multiple-files, wildmenu

I'd like to learn about using vim with multiple files without using external plugins.

I read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043196/2909897) that recommends putting the following in our `.vimrc`:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:full,full
```

Now when I use `:e <Tab>` I get the following output:

[image]

In this case, there is a file at `some/path/to/bar.rb` but vim is only showing me `some/`.

Some questions:

- From reading the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043196/2909897) I thought the list was supposed to be vertical. Why is it still horizontal?
- Is it possible for `wildmenu` to show the full path to `some/path/to/bar.rb`?
- Does my `vim .` followed by `:e <Tab>` pattern make sense? Is there a better way?

Comment: It is always horizontal and it is impossible to make it vertical.

Comment: I actually saw from the linked answer that they said `horizontal`, I just read it wrong. But is it possible to expand the paths?

Comment: yes that should be possible. I think the path is always relative to Vims `getcwd()` path, so simply do `:cd /` and it should work like you want.

Comment: How does `:cd /` help? It puts me in the root of my filesystem. I want `some/` to be expanded to `some/path/to/foo.rb` while in the menu.

Comment: You can use `<c-d>` to list out the possible completion candidates. This isn't exactly vertical, but might be closer to what you want. You can also use globs to go deeper into your directory structure e.g. `:e **/foo.rb<tab>`.

Comment: ah I misunderstood. In that case use `<c-d>` as Peter said.

Comment: @mbigras I'm currently using Neovim version 0.4.3, and the wildmenu seems to always display vertically...  I was more used to a horizontal display in Vim, but I don't know if it can be changed...

Answer (score 2):

If you want wildmenu to show vertically (like completion popup) you can use:

```
set wildoptions=pum
```

Help: [wildoptions](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildoptions%27) - available since vim9.0 [new-popup-compl](https://vimhelp.org/version9.txt.html#new-popup-compl)

If you want to complete on all files under the current working-directory you can use

```
:e **/*
```

or

```
:e some/**/*.rb
```

and press TAB.

Comment: Welcome vi.SE @dza :) Very nice answer, thanks for the helpful catch.